# Do I need to do any sort of mold mitigation after a bathtub leak damaged a ceiling?

Tags: plumbing, repair, leak, ceiling, mold

I recently purchased my first house and after the first time we went to use the jetted tub we noticed water damage on the ceiling in the kitchen below. So we got a plumber out there immediately and he determined that the drain needed to be replaced. He had to cut a hole in the ceiling to access the pipe because part of the drain pipe also needed replacement.

An approximately 2ft by 2ft section of ceiling was damaged by the initial leak. So we let it air out for a day and then my wife tried using the tub again. After she completed her bath I went downstairs to check for any more signs of water damage. That is when I found about a gallon or so of water on the floor.

I tested it, found that one of the jets was now leaking when water was in the tub and spraying when the jet was turned on. I got this new leak fixed and I have reason to believe the leaking problems have been resolved.

So at this point, before I have the ceiling repaired, do I need to do any sort of mold mitigation aside from letting it dry out for a few days?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not. One-time floods dry out quickly enough that there isn't really a chance for much to grow. Persistent/repeated moisture, over an extended period, is far more likely to cause trouble.

Comment: I agree with @keshlam.  Especially with the ceiling open, you can inspect for the presence of any black mold.  If there isn't any that you can't wipe away, you are set (after repairing the ceiling).

Comment: Awesome, I will get back up there this weekend and inspect and clean it up in there. I haven't seen any indication of mold thus far. Just a lot of dirt and sawdust from a terrible cleanup of the install.